# Gram-Schmidt-Complex

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

I have the following complex vectors:

[image: Here]

We need to apply Gram-Schmidt.

For $v_1$ I got the same vector as for $u_1$ that means $v_1=(0,0,0,0,1)$.

For $v_2' = u_2 \langle v_1,u_2 \rangle v1 $

So I calculated $\langle v_1,u_2 \rangle = (0,0,0,0,1)\cdot(0,0,1,0,i) = i$

 With that: $(0,0,1,0,i) - i\,(0,0,0,0,1) = (0,0,1,0,0)=v_2'$

 Moreover for $v_2$ i also got $(0,0,1,0,0)$ with $\|v_2\|=\sqrt{0^2+0^2+1^2+0^2+0^2} = \sqrt1 = 1\,(0,0,1,0,0)=(0,0,1,0,0)$

 For $v_3'=u_3-\langle v_1,u_3 \rangle v_1-\langle v_2,u_3 \rangle v_2$

 For $\langle v_1,u_3 \rangle =(0,0,0,0,1)\cdot(2,0,i,1,1)=1$

 For $\langle v_2,u_3 \rangle =(0,0,1,0,0)\cdot(2,0,i,1,1)=i$

With that $(2,0,i,1,1)-1\,(0,0,0,0,1)-i\,(0,0,1,0,0)=(2,0,i,0,0)-i\,(0,0,1,0,0)=(2,0,0,0,0)=v_3'$

 There is definitly a mistake here. So it would be really helpful if someone could help me here..

Comment: I would be really helpful if you showed more of your work.

Comment: Ok. I edited it

Comment: I’ve edited your question to make it more readable. Have a look at how my edit differs from what you had. For the future, please learn to use MathJax. You can find a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You’re much more likely to attract answers when people don’t have to slog through nigh-unreadable questions.

Comment: Thank you so much man.. I am still a noob at this, so I will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2,0,i,1,1)-(0,0,0,0,1)\ne(2,0,i,0,0)$. You dropped the $1$ in the fourth slot.

Comment: (2,0,i,1,1)−(0,0,0,0,1) = (2,0,i,1,0) With that I would get =             (2,0,i,1,0) -i(0,0,1,0,0)= (2,0,0,1,0)

Comment: @PhysX Yes, but that’s not what you’ve got in the work that you show in your question.

Comment: Are v'2 and v2 even right? I am really not sure about this.

Comment: @PhysX They are. You just made a simple arithmetic error when computing $v_3'$.

Comment: I calculated the rest. For v'3=(2,0,0,1,0).  For v3= $\sqrt5$ * (2,0,0,1,0). v'4 = (1/5, 2i, 0,-2/5, 0) and v4= $\sqrt24/5 \ $ *(1/5, 2i, 0 ,-2/5,0)  ^^

Comment: @PhysX You can check your work by assembling the resulting vectors into a matrix $M$ and seeing if $M^\dagger M=I$. You can also augment the original set of basis vectors with these and row-reduce to make sure that you haven’t added anything to the span.